How to convert timestamp to equivalent UTC time in Azure LogicApps
In a http request it returns a property of birthday in response it's value is coming as a timestamp. How to convert it to equivalent UTC time in a logicapp action of 'Compose'.
input : "birthDay": "/Date(1723529264000)/"
output : "birthday": "2024-08-13T02:12:16Z"
if(
    and(
        not(empty(items('For_each')?['student'])),
        not(empty(items('For_each')?['student']['results'])),
        greater(length(items('For_each')?['student']['results']), 0),
        not(empty(items('For_each')?['student']['results']?[0]?['birthDay']))
    ),
    formatDateTime(
        addToTime(
            '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z',
            div(
                int(substring(
                    items('For_each')?['student']['results']?[0]?['birthDay'],
                    6,
                    sub(
                        length(items('For_each')?['student']['results']?[0]?['birthDay']),
                        8
                    )
                )),
                1000
            ),
            'Second'
        ),
        'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'
    ),
    null
)

This code gives the correct format but the expected output is differs , showing invalid date and time.

can you share the screenshot of the output you are getting

@IkhtesamAfrin "1969-12-22T02:12:16Z"

So you are getting incorrect date month and year?
